# Що означає фразеологізм "гулькин ніс"?

Tags: значення-слів, фразеологізми

Гортаючи Інтернет-сторінки щодо різноманітних вишиванок, наштовхнулася на цікавий фразеологізм у такому контексті (стаття "[Знову з Борщева. Там все так само цвітуть вишиванки](https://kamienczanka.livejournal.com/240098.html)":

> Тим більш, що і писати важко, і народу ж зараз з **гулькин ніс**.

[СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghuljkyn_nis), на  жаль, інформації не подає.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Це фразеологізм [російського походження](https://phraseologiya.academic.ru/919/%D1%81_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81), що означає *дуже мало*. В українській мові наявний гарний відповідник **як кіт наплакав**. На одному із [сайтів](http://ualingret.ru/faq/18698-znachennja-frazeologizmu-jak-kit-naplakav-istorija.html) знайшла цікаву інформацію щодо походження цього фразеологізму:

> Фразеологізм **«як кіт наплакав»** безпосередньо пов`язаний з дзьобом голуба. Цих птахів як зазвичай кличуть? «Гулі-гулі-гулі» - в наслідування їх «розмови». І самих цих пернатих стали ласкаво так само називати. А дзьоб - ніс голуба, гульки - в порівнянні з її тілом дуже навіть маленьке. Ось таке лексико-генетичне походження: **«як кіт наплакав»** - отже, щось надзвичайно маленьке, ну просто з голубиний дзьобик.

Отже, в даному Вами контексті: **Тим більш, що і писати важко, і народу ж зараз дуже мало**.

Comment: Дуже схоже що ualingret.ru використовує чужі матеріали перекладені роботом. Звідси і такі очевидні неоковирності "кіт наплакав безпосередньо пов`язаний з дзьобом голуба." Мабуть не варто посилатися на такі джерела